# code after a nested foreach in a foreach doesn't execute as expected

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<float, float>> sysCoordTop in allSysCoords) 
{
    List<string> tempNameList = new List<string>();

    float xTop = sysCoordTop.Value.Key;
    float yTop = sysCoordTop.Value.Value;

    string nameTop = sysCoordTop.Key;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<float, float>> sysCoordBottom in allSysCoords) {
        float xBottom = sysCoordBottom.Value.Key;
        float yBottom = sysCoordBottom.Value.Value;

        float xDiff = System.Math.Abs(xTop - xBottom);
        float yDiff = System.Math.Abs(yTop - yBottom);

        string nameBottom = sysCoordBottom.Key;

        if (xDiff < 5f && yDiff < 5f && nameBottom != nameTop) {
            tempNameList.Add(nameBottom);
            Debug.Log($"{nameBottom} added to temp list at {nameTop}");
        }
    }

    sysDict.Add(nameTop, tempNameList);
    Debug.Log("temp list written to dict");
    tempNameList.Clear();
}
```

My problem is that the lines below do not execute when I expected them to, but rather they execute once before the nested loop, even though I assumed them to execute once every iteration of the first foreach loop.

```cs
sysDict.Add(nameTop, tempNameList);
Debug.Log("temp list written to dict");
tempNameList.Clear();
```

Now, I'm well aware that this way of nesting loops is not the best way to do things. I'm **not** asking this is to get unhelpful comments about how bad it is to write with nested loops. I'm asking this to get an answer to the question I asked. If you do however decide to inform me of how bad it is to write nested loops, please also enlighten me on how I should do it instead.

Comment: Have you ever considered using `var`?

Comment: `var` would shorten your `for` loop to `foreach (var sysCoordTop in allSysCoords)`

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that, but I probably should have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use Clear method on tempItem, instead re-initialize that object at start of each iteration.

Clearing it will clear the item in list as well.

When you add the object to dictionary, you add reference and not the values. When you clear the object, you clear values and everything referencing that object will have the same effect (no values). Instead of clearing, re-initialize the object

Comment: and here I was thinking that it was something completely different, thanks

Comment: So it's not that the code was actually being executed out of order, just that `tempNameList` being added to `sysDict` and then `Clear()`ed made it appear so?  I'm confused, but that makes more sense than explaining the out-of-order execution.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted.  I understand how calling `tempNameList.Clear()` is problematic.  I'm just not clear on how that is the ultimate solution to the problem.  My only guess is when the question says the code executes out of order that was based on observing the results rather than actually stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: it was based on the debug logs appearing out of order with `Debug.Log("temp list written to dict");` getting logged only once, so I obviously assumed that it was executing out of order